# Assembly InpOut32.dll polling from a usb port

Tags: dll, assembly, x86, usb

Is there a way to use InpOut32.dll to poll for input from a USB port? I have a parallel port to USB adapter and the driver it installed is USB Printing Support. Is there a way to find the hex value of the port? I'm going to write this in MASM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *not* possible to use an USB->Parport Adapter with InpOut.dll - these adapters work only with printers. They speak the printer protocol over USB.

These adapter types simply provide no port to control for InpOut.dll.

You might get away with a PCI/PICe parport adapter, these have I/O ports.